# httpPost return Page not found HTTP ERROR 405 ASP.NET CORE MVC IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express

i have problem with form when i put in my Controller httpPost the Error http 405 it showing to me

every step i made its correct

my code

```
@model security.Models.ContactUs
<div class="contact_box">
    <form id="Contact" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact" method="POST">
        <input type="text" asp-for="Name" placeholder="Your Name">
        <input type="email" asp-for="Email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" asp-for="PhoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <input type="text" asp-for="Text" placeholder="Message">

        <button type="submit">Contact Us</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and my Controller

```
namespace security.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller

    {

        DBContext db;
        public  HomeController(DBContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        //private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        //public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        //{
        //    _logger = logger;
            
        //}
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            CollectionsData model = new CollectionsData();
            model.Offers = GetOffers();
            model.Services = GetServices();
            model.News = GetNews();
            model.Team = GetSecurityTeam();

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Contact(ContactUs model)
        {
            db.Contactus.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        
        }

       
   public IActionResult Services( Sevices model)
        {
            var ModelServices = db.Sevices.ToList();
            return View(ModelServices);
        }

        //[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        //public IActionResult Error()
        //{
        //    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        //}


        public IEnumerable<Offers> GetOffers()
        {
            return db.Offers.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Sevices> GetServices()
        {
            return db.Sevices.ToList();

        }

        public IEnumerable<ourNews> GetNews()
        {
            return db.News.ToList();

        }


        public IEnumerable<SecurityTeam> GetSecurityTeam()
        {
            return db.Team.ToList();

        }

      

    }
}
```

But when I delete httppost everything works fine except sending the form to the database

i don't why the page its not load its give HTTP ERROR 405

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to place a submit button inside of the  form

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact" method="POST">
    ....your code

    <button type="submit">Contact Us</button>
</form>
```

or for some reason sometimes this works better

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   ....your code

    <button type="submit">Contact Us</button>
}
```

and you need Contact get action to create a contact view

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            var model= new ContactUs();
            return View(model)
        }
```

Comment: I did, but its still the same error I think the problem from the IIS but I don't know from where I start because when i delete httpPost, the page its load but I cannot POST anything in the database

Comment: @ibrahimmohamed Can you porst the full view code , not just the part pls?

Comment: I Put the full Controller can you check pls

Comment: @ibrahimmohamed I need to see the full view, not a controller

Comment: i am already add the View, its just contain html code for contact us view

Comment: And what is the name of this view? and what is a get action that  creates the view?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<form id="contact"  method="POST" asp-action="Contact"> 
  ...     
</form>
```

Comment: thanks but its still same error HTTP ERROR 405

Comment: try using action instead of asp-action too

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score -1):

`return View()` doesn’t make any sense from an HTTP Verb perspective. Your form is POSTing correctly, but when you’re returning the view you need to change it to redirect to your GET action. I don’t know know what your entire controller looks like but I suspect this is the issue with naming.

Try
`return RedirectToAction(“VIEWNAME”)`

Comment: Thanks for response but the result it's still same it's give me This page isn't working HTTP error 405

Comment: Can you post your full controller

Comment: ok you can check now